# Keep getting an error on macOS when trying to use Passkeys to login

Tags: ios, swift, macos, authentication, passkey

I keep getting the following error when trying to run Passkey sign in on macOS.

> Told not to present authorization sheet: Error
> Domain=com.apple.AuthenticationServicesCore.AuthorizationError Code=1
> "(null)"

The same piece of code is working as expected on iOS.

Some more info:

- The association file and entitlements are correct and validated as everything is working on iOS.
- The app is built on SwiftUI and use the same codebase for macOS and iOS
- Validated that the presentation anchor is also correct on macOS because other SSO login works with the same presentation anchor.

Not sure where the problem is. Followed https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/public-private_key_authentication/supporting_passkeys/ to get the integration.